# Insert if DNE else update Mysql row

Tags: mysql

I am trying to us `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' but it keeps adding a new row instead of updating.

```
INSERT INTO favorites (userid, topicid) 
VALUES ('2', '50')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
active = 0;
```

my favorites table is set up as follows:

```
favoritesid (AI)
userid
topicid
active (boolean)
```

If the userid and topicid already exist (both of them in the same row), then I just want to change `active` to 0.

Is this possible?

Comment: In order to hit `ON DUPLICATE KEY` the key has to exists prior of your insert. Is that really the case? Are the fields really a unique key (primary key, unique index)?

Comment: I would say no.  Is there an alternative way of doing this in a single query, when they aren't?

Comment: If there aren't unique keys in there, it won't help you tu use `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. Either add a unique key or you have to query first to find out if your value already exists in your table before inserting.

Comment: Ok thank you, I plan on doing the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hit `ON DUPLICATE KEY` the key has to exists prior of your insert. If there aren't unique keys in there, it won't help you tu use it.

Either add a unique key or you have to query first to find out if your value already exists in your table before inserting.